# Access images from other drive with flask

Tags: python, flask

My flask application is in my C: drive. The images I want to display on my flask server are on my D: drive because there are 160 GB of them, which my C: drive does not like to store. I was wondering how to access these files outside of the root of the flask application. Any help is appreciated!

SOLVED [Thanks to Shivendra Pratap Kushwaha]

I was able to access the other drive with the following test code:

HTML with Jinja2:

```
<img id="myimage9" src="{{ url_for('main.sendfiletest') }}" width="400" height="300" alt="TestLabel">
```

Python 3.7:

```
from flask import send_file

@main.route('/uploads/')
def sendfiletest():
    test_url = "D:\myimage.png"
    return send_file(test_url, mimetype='image/jpg')
```

Thanks for everyone for trying to help me out!

Comment: try with this :
from flask import send_file

file = "D:\your\file\name"
return send_file(file, mimetype='image/jpg')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code in your routes.py :

```
from flask import send_file 
file = "D:\your\file\name" 
return send_file(file, mimetype='image/jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to expose images stored on your computer? Does that mean your computer is supposed to be the server of your flask app?

You could store your images on a AWS S3 bucket or Google Drive and store the links to these images in your flask app.

Comment: Yes the app is just for local use only. So I would like it for the computer to be the server. For your solution, I also have the images on a OneDrive, is the same solution valid for OneDrive?

Comment: I don't know how OneDrive works, but if you can browse your images on the OneDrive web app, you should be able to get a link for each image and store those links in your database so that you put it as the `src` of the `<img />`